# LINQ apply filter in where clause only if parameter value greater than Zero?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using LINQ to retrieve records from the database. Everything is working fine, except I need to apply the different filters in a single query. If the parameters are not `Null`  greater than zero then show all the Employees records. Otherwise, if they are `Null` or less than zero, then don't apply the filters. Following is my current appraoch:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployee(int? JobTitleId, int? GenderId)
{
   var Emloyees = db.Employees.ToList();

   if(JobTitleId > 0)
   {
      Emloyees = Emloyees.Where(e => e.JobTitleId == JobTitleId).ToList();
   }

   if(GenderId> 0)
   {
      Emloyees = Emloyees.Where(e => e.GenderId == GenderId).ToList();
   }

}
```

Is there any way to apply this to single query?. I want to do if `JobTitleId` and `GenderId` is `Null` then show other records, otherwise, filter them.

Comment: It would be better to use `if(JobTitleId.HasValue)` etc since its nullable, but what you doing is the correct approach

Comment: if your query is going to be more complex, this link can help you [Build Where Clause Dynamically in Linq](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq)

Comment: Note also you should delete the `.ToList()` in your queries (and if you do want to make it `List<T>`, do that after all the queries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the predicates to the `IQueryable`, i.e. remove `ToList`:

```
var employees = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

if (JobTitleId.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)
{
   employees = employees.Where(e => e.JobTitleId == JobTitleId);
}
```

etc.

When *after* this you call`employees.ToList()` the predicates will be translated into SQL and you'll pull less data from the database. The statements above only *build* the query and don't *execute* it.

Comment: For better performance, I use `AsQueryable` and apply my filters and then use `ToList`?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903050/foreign-key-object-missing-in-linq-groupby). It is related to above question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to do same thing with include operation and AsQueryable really did the job

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension method to conditionally apply the filter:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

Usage:

```
var employees = db.Employees
   .WhereIf(JobTitleId.HasValue, e => e.JobTitleId == JobTitleId)
   .WhereIf(GenderId.HasValue, e => e.GenderId == GenderId)
   .ToList();
```

Also, use `HasValue` instead of comparing to 0 for nullable integers.

Comment: This is a nice little extension method. It makes the code nicely succinct.

Comment: Was looking for something like this for ages. Great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

hope this solves,

```
         List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>();
            emplist.Add(new Employee() {EmpName="A",JobTitleId=0,GenderId=0 });
            emplist.Add(new Employee() { EmpName = "B", JobTitleId = 1, GenderId = 0 });
            emplist.Add(new Employee() { EmpName = "C", JobTitleId = 0, GenderId = 1 });
            emplist.Add(new Employee() { EmpName = "D", JobTitleId = 1, GenderId = 1 });
            int jobid = 1;
            int genderid = 1;
            var result = from em in emplist where ((em.JobTitleId > 0 && em.JobTitleId == jobid) ||  (em.GenderId > 0 && em.GenderId == genderid)) select em;           
            foreach (Employee emp in result)
                Console.WriteLine(emp.EmpName);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
Emloyees = Emloyees.Where(e=> (JobTitleId > 0 && e.JobTitleId == JobTitleId) || e.GenderId == GenderId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do:

```
var emloyees = db.Employees.Where(e => (!JobTitleId.HasValue && !GenderId.HasValue) || (JobTitleId > 0 && e.JobTitleId == JobTitleId) || (GenderId > 0 && e.GenderId == GenderId))
```

but that makes it a lot more complicated than your current solution.

Building your LINQ using if statements is generally the way to go.

Comment: *a lot more complicated* That, and the null checks become part of the SQL query, needlessly troubling the database's query optimizer.

Comment: This is one example. I have many functions with many parameters.