# Foreign Key Object Missing in LINQ GroupBy?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by, foreign-keys

I am using `GroupBy` in my `LINQ` queries. My query is working fine, except my foreign key objects are missing. Then, I tried to add `Include` in my query. Following is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
{
     var Emloyees = db.Employees.AsQueryable();
     Emloyees.GroupBy(e=> new {e.JobTitleId, e.GenderId})
             .Select(tr => new MyObject
                 SalaryTotal = tr.Sum(r=>r.Salary)
              }).Include(tr=>tr.JobTitle).Include(tr=>tr.Gender).ToList();
}
```

I am getting this exception:

> The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types.

I tried to add it before `GroupBy` and directly in `db.Employees.AsQueryable()`, but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can only use `Include` on mapped entity types. `MyObject` isn't a mapped type. You should make `JobTitle` and `Gender` part of `MyObject`. `Include` directly after `db.Employees` will be ignored because the end result doesn't consist of employees.

Comment: So whats the solution for it? I have JobTitle and Gender in my `MyObject` Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a projection with the .Select(...), after which your includes cannot be resolved. The result of that query will be a list MyObject, which does not work for includes that are actually on Employee.

So Try it like this:

```
Emloyees
    .GroupBy(e=> new {e.JobTitleId, e.GenderId})
    .Select(tr => new MyObject {
        SalaryTotal = tr.Sum(r=>r.Salary),
        JobTitle = tr.FirstOrDefault().JobTitle,
        Gender = tr.FirstOrDefault().Gender
    }).ToList();
```

You will have to extend MyObject with 2 additional properties, but the result of your query will be what you want (I assume).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Perfect.

Comment: This works fine, since the group is being done by `JobTitleId` and `GenderId`.